# Looking for wysiwyg editor for rails5 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm making nonprofit blog site which user can post text and upload picture.  So i'm trying to add wysiwyg editor to users's post page. 
My qustion is:

•Is there any free editor which i can user for my rails project? 
I've checked Froala,TinyMCE,quill,and CKEditor(Quill seems free)
I need upload picture function.

•Also could you tell me the definition of commercial use? (For ex:  If i use CKEditor to my blog site, is that commercial use?).

Sorry for silly question. Thank you for help.

Comment: https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails

Comment: https://trix-editor.org

Comment: use paperclip, carrierwave or shrine for the image upload to Amazon or other cloud service. Save the text in the database through Trix, tiny mce or whatever but sanitize it before you do it. Maybe some editors can have image embedded into the text and tdo the job of Paperclip or Carrierwave.. but I am not sure.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I checked Tiny mce and Trix. Is tiny mce free? I think i will select Froala. Thanks for advice!!